# Mutation step/symbol size when plotting haplotype networks with pegas

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I've been trying to figure out how to make the little circles that represent mutation steps on a haplotype network bigger. For whatever reason, all the normal ways I'd think don't seem to be working. It seems like no matter what I do, the symbols remain tiny. What am I missing?

Here's a base bit of sample code:

```
data(woodmouse)
h <- haplotype(woodmouse)
net <- haploNet(h)
plot(net, size=attr(net,"freq")*3,bg=pal,labels=F, fast=F, legend=F, 
      show.mutation=T,threshold=0)
# using scale.ratio = 1, the mutations are visisble
plot(net, size=attr(net,"freq")*3,bg=pal,labels=F, fast=F, legend=F, 
      show.mutation=T,threshold=0,scale.ratio=3)
# but using scale.ratio=3, they get tiny / disappear
```

You can see the mutations here, but if I set `scale.ratio` to something bigger (a requirement with my own data), they essentially disappear.

I've tried passing a larger `cex` to plot (doesn't work) as well as setting `cex` globally with par (makes the whole plot smaller for some reason).

It seems like the circles are scaled with the lines, but I don't know how to control that. Is it even possible? Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: (Not my downvote.) Downvotes generally mean your question doesn't make sense to a person with a programming perspective. There's an expectation that you should be able to cut and paste code that will run. They probably don't know what package these functions come from and think that it was impolite of you to expect the rest of us to go look up something that you _should_ have explained. (People should explain their downvotes, but people have gotten weary of typing out the same old explanations that perhaps should have been obvious. Please don't protest. Just fix your question with an edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cex` controls the font size and will not help with graphics size. From the help page for the `haploNet` and `plot.haploNet` functions:

```
?haploNet
```

> **size:** a numeric vector giving the diameter of the circles representing the haplotypes: this is in the same unit than the links and eventually recycled.
>   **scale.ratio:** the ratio of the scale of the links representing the number of steps on the scale of the circles representing the haplotypes. It may be needed to give a value greater than one to avoid overlapping circles.

This means that size of the links (circles representing mutations between haplotypes) is relative to the size of the haplotypes. To relatively enlarge the link size, you need to find a suitable combination of the two arguments.

```
set.seed(123)
net <- haploNet(haplotype(woodmouse[sample(15, size = 50, replace = TRUE), ]))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(net, size=attr(net,"freq"), labels=F, fast=F, legend=F, 
   show.mutation=T, threshold=0, scale.ratio=1)
plot(net, size=attr(net,"freq")*.2, labels=F, fast=F, legend=F, 
   show.mutation=T, threshold=0, scale.ratio=.2)
```

Enlarging circle size with `haploNet` runs into a risk that circles will overlap and the visible number of mutations will be incorrect. Use discretion with visualization and in case of problems, consider haplotype network calculation in `TCS` software where unsampled mutations are displayed with vertical bars or `Network` from Fluxus with proportional link lengths.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. It's not clear to me why multiplying by 0.2 would make things bigger, but I expect I'll figure it out.

Comment: @LutherBlissett The circle sizes are relative and the plotting function adjusts the actual sizes for optimal display of the relationships. If the answer solved your question, consider accepting in: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done, @nya. I think my original misconception w/r/t cex comes from [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html), in which it says that the parameter controls "the amount by which plotting text and symbols should be scaled relative to the default".